# List all child nodes of a parent node in a treeview control in Visual C#

Tags: c#, treeview

I have a treeview control, and it contains a single parent node and several child nodes from that parent.  Is there a way to obtain an array or list of all the child nodes from the main parent? i.e. getting all the nodes from treeview.nodes[0], or the first parent node.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add to a list recursively like this:

```
public void AddChildren(List<TreeNode> Nodes, TreeNode Node)
{
    foreach (TreeNode thisNode in Node.Nodes)
    {
        Nodes.Add(thisNode);
        AddChildren(Nodes, thisNode);
    }
}
```

Then call this routine passing in the root node:

```
List<TreeNode> Nodes = new List<TreeNode>();
AddChildren(Nodes, treeView1.Nodes[0]);
```

Comment: Thank you for this code! I had to change the foreach to make it work though, like this: foreach (TreeNode thisNode in Node.ChildNodes) <-- Node.ChildNodes instead of Node.Nodes

Comment: @Svein that's because you are using WPF but this code is for WinForms. There is no ChildNodes in WinForms.

Answer (score 10):

```
public IEnumerable<TreeNode> GetChildren(TreeNode Parent)
{
    return Parent.Nodes.Cast<TreeNode>().Concat(
           Parent.Nodes.Cast<TreeNode>().SelectMany(GetChildren));
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You could do something like this .. to get the all nodes in tree view ..

```
 private void PrintRecursive(TreeNode treeNode)
 {
     // Print the node.
      System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(treeNode.Text);
      MessageBox.Show(treeNode.Text);
      // Print each node recursively.
       foreach (TreeNode tn in treeNode.Nodes)
       {
           PrintRecursive(tn);
        }
 }

   // Call the procedure using the TreeView.
 private void CallRecursive(TreeView treeView)
 {
      // Print each node recursively.
        TreeNodeCollection nodes = treeView.Nodes;
         foreach (TreeNode n in nodes)
         {
             PrintRecursive(n);
          }
   }
```

would you pls take alook at this link .

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wwc698z7.aspx